# Wrong button activation

Tags: java

I want the button I click on to get disabled and display the image but the following program is disabling the last button in the frame regardless of whichever button I click, What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TicTacToe{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                JFrame frame=new GameFrame();
                frame.setTitle("BATTLESHIPS");
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Image img=new ImageIcon("icon.gif").getImage();
                frame.setIconImage(img);
            }
        });
    }
}


class GamePanel extends JPanel{
    private JPanel panel;
    private boolean start;
    private ActionListener listener;
    public GamePanel(){
        start=true;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        listener=new ClickButton();

        addButton("");
        addButton("");
        addButton("");
        addButton("");
        addButton("");
        addButton("");
        addButton("");
        addButton("");
        addButton("");

        add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    void addButton(String label){
        JButton button=new JButton(label);
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        panel.add(button);
    }



    class ClickButton implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            String input=event.getActionCommand();
            if(start){
                {
                Image img=new ImageIcon("icon.gif").getImage();
                button.setText("");
                button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                button.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class GameFrame extends JFrame{
    public GameFrame(){
        add(new GamePanel());
        pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have asked 7 questions so far, and never accepted an answer. Do you know that you should accept the answer that helped you the most, so the answerer gets rewarded by his effort to help you? Do you know how to accept an answer? Please, take a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Sorry I really didn't know that :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're disabling `button` which is the last one you have added.

You should use the clicked button instead, which you can obtain with `event.getSource()`. It should look like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            String input=event.getActionCommand();
            if(start){
                {
                Image img=new ImageIcon("icon.gif").getImage();
                JButton clicked = (JButton)event.getSource();
                clicked.setText("");
                clicked.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                clicked.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @HugoSousa Because the `button` field would still contain a bogus value, and the data structure wouldn't reflect what's actually on the screen. With your solution this listener would work but the rest of the code would still be wrong. The solution would be either to remove the `button` field altogether or replace it with a collection that contains all the buttons created.

Comment: @biziclop what changes should I make in the code in order to make it right?

Comment: @biziclop Probably the OP doesn't even need that `JButton` anywhere. But I think he gets the idea that `button` is actually refering to the last button created/added.

Comment: @user3798851 We were all newbies so I know how it feels. In this case, as @HugoSousa says, what you need to do is get rid of the `button` field altogether. It doesn't really buy you anything and as you can see, it can easily mislead readers of the code.

Comment: @biziclop I don't understand what you trying to say :|

Comment: @user3798851 Just remove `button` from your class members. You don't need it. In the `addButton` method, just create a new instance -  `JButton button = new JButton(label);` - and add it, that's it.

Comment: What's the difference between the two??

Comment: @user3798851 As you have it now, `button` is your class member, that you have defined before with `private JButton button;`. That's what we're saying that you don't need. The way I said it, `button` will just be accessible inside the method, and then it's gone.

Comment: @user3798851 You shouldn't edit the code directly, now it's not compilable, because `button` inside the listener will give an error. Also, you should accept the answer that helped you the most, rewarding the effort spent by the answerer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The action listener refers only to `button`, which will be the value of the last button created.

Comment: And to make matters worse, all the other buttons you haven't even got a reference for, as you overwrote it in `addButton()`. So to answer the question precisely, what you're doing wrong is the `addButton()` method and the fact that you overwrite the value of `button` every time without checking anything.